Multivariate forecast in NeuralProphet
I'm trying to build a global model to predict two time series at the same time. The code below works with no error. But the forecast dataframe has all NaN corresponding to one of the two IDs (i.e. there are two time series). The yhat values are also all NaN. Am I doing something wrong or missing?
m = NeuralProphet(
    yearly_seasonality=True,
    weekly_seasonality=True,
    daily_seasonality=False,  
    quantiles=quantiles,
    n_lags=60,
    epochs=100,
    n_forecasts=30,
    loss_func='Huber',
)
m.set_plotting_backend('plotly')
m.highlight_nth_step_ahead_of_each_forecast(step_number=10)

metrics = m.fit(train_df[['ds', 'y', 'ID']])

df_future = m.make_future_dataframe(
    train_df, 
    n_historic_predictions=True,   
)

forecast = m.predict(df_future)

